# how to configure user migration in Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, auth0

I am trying to migrate users from Auth0 to Azure AD B2C and I don't have access to user passwords. Following is the flow I am planning based on some custom policy flows recommended by Azure AD B2C [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration):

1. Pre-migrate users (without passwords)to ADB2C and mark them for migration
2. Redirect user to sign in to Azure AD B2C from my application
3. AD will check the user status and call the specified legacy API endpoint with username and password
4. Auth0 endpoint will validate the user credentials
5. AD will set the password for the user

Auth0 has a [simple endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#resource-owner-password), which expects an HTTP Post like so:

```
POST https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&audience=API_IDENTIFIER&scope=SCOPE&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
```

I was hoping to configure a simple script that Azure AD could run that would make the above Post request for each user by substituting the entered credentials. However, looking at some of the instructions, it seems [extremely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro) complicated. Is there a simple guide to how I can set this up in Azure for the above?